# How can I configure Calico to use a custom subnet as the default?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, calico

I have been able to create a Kubernetes cluster  on CoreOS using Calico following this [guide](https://github.com/caseydavenport/kubernetes/blob/calico-cni-coreos-doc/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/bare_metal_calico.md).

As documented in the guide, Calico creates a default subnet 192.168.0.0/16. Once the services start, I can redefine the subnet by running the following commands:

```
$ export ETCD_AUTHORITY=127.0.0.1:6666
$ calicoctl pool remove 192.168.0.0/16
$ calicoctl pool add 10.244.0.0/16 --nat-outgoing
```

All work nicely. However, I would like to automate the above using cloud-config. I've tried using a OneShot service to execute the commands but it only worked partially. The new subnet 10.244.0.0/16 was added but 192.168.0.0/16 was not removed. The error was:

```
calicoctl[1330]: 192.168.0.0/16 is not a configured pool.
```

I guess that was because the default subnet was not yet created when the `pool remove` command executed.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to configure Calico so it uses my custom subnet as
   the default?
2. If not, then is there a way to poll for Calico to
   initialize completely before executing `pool remove` on the default
   subnet?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party here, but...

With recent releases of Calico this is easier to automate.  The `calico/node` container will attempt to create the `192.168.0.0/16` pool by default.  If you'd like to use a different pool you can do the following:

1. Before running the `calico/node` container, create the pool you'd like to use.
2. Start the `calico/node` container with NO_DEFAULT_POOLS=true environment variable.  This stops the container from creating the default pool. (https://github.com/projectcalico/calico-containers/blob/master/calico_node/filesystem/startup.py#L259)

Using cloud-init / systemd, I'd do something like this:

```
[Service]
Environment=ETCD_AUTHORITY=$private_ipv4:2379
Environment=NO_DEFAULT_POOLS=true
ExecStartPre=/opt/bin/calicoctl pool add <your ipv4 pool> --nat-outgoing
ExecStartPre=/opt/bin/calicoctl pool add <your ipv6 pool>
ExecStart=/opt/bin/calicoctl node --ip=$private_ipv4 --detach=false
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```